# How to combine multiple ActiveRecord query results into one and a count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have an `Order` model that `has_many` `OrderItem`s. `OrderItem` `belongs_to` `Product` and `Order`.

```
create_table "order_items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "product_id"
  t.integer  "order_id"
  t.decimal  "unit_price",  precision: 10, scale: 2
  t.integer  "quantity"
  t.decimal  "total_price", precision: 10, scale: 2
  t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
  t.string   "cat"
end

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "location_id"
  t.string   "day"
  t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
  t.decimal  "subtotal",    precision: 12, scale: 3
  t.decimal  "total",       precision: 12, scale: 3
  t.integer  "role"
  t.text     "notes"
end
```

There are a few different `Location`s/users and each `Location` has one `Order` per day. I can list the products for each `Location` and each day by

```
@order = Order.where(location: @location, day: 'Wednesday')
@order_items = @order.order_items
```

I want to be able to show every item ordered per day from all locations combined, but what I have produces replicas of items if they appear in each order. Is there some way to 'merge' some of the values from each `@order_items` array?

If location 1 orders 1 bread on Wednesday and location 2 orders 3 breads on Wednesday, then I want to create an array that has only one bread item with a quantity of 4. What I have below gives me an array with two bread items in the array, one for each day.

```
@locations = Location.all
@order = Order.where(location: @locations, day: 'Wednesday')
@order_items = OrderItem.where(order: @order)
```

I realise this can be done by iterating through the array and creating a new one, but is there a better or Rails way of doing it?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question - do you want to sum all the orders for a given location and day into a single order?

Comment: @FredWillmore no, I want to sum all the orders for every location on a given day

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
OrderItem.joins(:order).group(:location_id).group(:day).sum(:quantity)
```

This will give you a hash that looks like this:

```
{[1, "Thursday"]=>4, [1, "Wednesday"]=>2}
```

I actually didn't know you could use an array as a hash index but there it is. The array which serves as the hash key is composed of location_id and day.